# How to get items from django user foreign key

Tags: django

How do I retrieve items from django foreign keys attached to a user account?

```
class product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_title =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    product_price =  models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    product_image =  models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

I looked into some other stack overflow question and tried request.user.product.product_title but that just returns an Attribute error,'User' object has no attribute 'product'. I also tried request.user.product_set.all() but that just returns this queryset:

```
<QuerySet [<product: product object (2)>, <product: product object (3)>, <product: product object (4)>]>
```

I tried some other things too but I can't remember what exactly and what error those threw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queryset you are getting when you do `request.user.product_set.all()` are all the products that has that user as FK. Now you just need to work with that.

## edit 1

```
for product in request.user.product_set.all():
    print(product.title)
```

Comment: Okay but how do I get like the data inside that query set out?

Comment: Well, that is really up to you, eg `product = request.user.product_set.all()[0]`

Comment: Let me clarify, I want it to go all a users product_title and print it out not just the first instance. I'm thinking a for loop but I don't know how to get the user product title our of that queryset

Comment: If you want to print all the products title from that user, then you could loop on the query set and print (I will edit the answer for better coding)